# Server-Sent Events occasionally become malformed when sent in rapid succession

Tags: c#, .net, server-sent-events

I've written a very basic game in .NET 7 that relies on server-sent events. I've noticed that my event content is occasionally malformed. From what I can tell this happens during small periods of time in which there are several updates in quick succession.

Below is an example - notice the `Data` for the highlighted record is malformed. In another instance that I did not screenshot, the *data* was fine, but the *event type* was `lobbyevent:lobbyEvent` instead of simply `lobbyEvent`.

[image: Event Stream]

I have to imagine that, somehow, the `ResponseBody` is not being properly flushed, and/or being "cross-contaminated" due to concurrent requests. The logging in the following code tells me that it's all working as expected up to the point where it sends response data. Furthermore, the problem seems worse out in the wild, as opposed to my localhost where it's much more difficult to replicate - this would seem to align with the idea that slower response times are causing concurrency issues.

My code is below, which was built following the patterns outlined [here](https://github.com/Nordes/Sample.SSEvent). Can anyone help me out? Am I correct in my assumption, and what can I do to remedy the issue?

```cs
[Produces("text/event-stream")]
[HttpGet("{code}/listen")]
public async Task ListenForNotifications(string code, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    _logger.LogCritical($"CONNECTED");
    var lobby = await _dbContext.Lobbies.FirstOrDefaultAsync(l => l.JoinCode == code);
    if (lobby == null) return;

    SetServerSentEventHeaders();
    await Response.WriteAsync($"event:connected\n", cancellationToken);
    await Response.Body.FlushAsync(cancellationToken);

    async void OnNotification(object? sender, LobbyEventArgs eventArgs)
    {
        try
        {
            if (eventArgs.LobbyEvent.LobbyId != lobby.Id) return;
            var json = JsonSerializer.Serialize(eventArgs.LobbyEvent, _jsonSerializerOptions);
            await Response.WriteAsync("retry:10000\n", cancellationToken);
            await Response.WriteAsync($"event:lobbyEvent\n", cancellationToken);
            await Response.WriteAsync($"data:{json}\n\n", cancellationToken);
            await Response.Body.FlushAsync(cancellationToken);
            _logger.LogCritical($"NOTIFICATION SENT: {eventArgs.LobbyEvent.Type}");
        } catch (Exception ex)
        {
            _logger.LogCritical($"NOTIFICATION FAILED: {ex.Message}");
        }
    }

    async void KeepAlive(object? sender, EventArgs eventArgs)
    {
        await Response.WriteAsync("event:keep-alive\n", cancellationToken);
        await Response.WriteAsync("data:keep-alive\n\n", cancellationToken);
        await Response.Body.FlushAsync(cancellationToken);
    }

    _eventService.LobbyEvent += OnNotification;
    _eventService.KeepAlive += KeepAlive;

    try
    {
        while (!cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested)
            await Task.Delay(1000, cancellationToken);
    }
    finally
    {
        _logger.LogCritical($"DISCONNECTED");
        _eventService.LobbyEvent -= OnNotification;
        _eventService.KeepAlive -= KeepAlive;
    }
}

private void SetServerSentEventHeaders()
{
    Response.StatusCode = 200;
    Response.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "text/event-stream");
    Response.Headers.Add("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
    Response.Headers.Add("Connection", "keep-alive");
}
```

Comment: I have to imagine you'd be a lot better off using SignalR for this, especially since it supports multiple transport types.

Comment: @DavidL Given that this is a personal project, seems like a nice opportunity to pick it up and learn something new. That said, while ultimately I will likely go down that road, I'm still curious what exactly the issue is with this code above.

Comment: `"cross-contaminated" due to concurrent requests` - most likely this is the cause. I don't see any synchronization of the writing going on here.